# Configure WiFi router using Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi, router

I want to develop app which will Configure (Changing router ip, password, wep key etc) Wifi router from my iphone. 
How will i do that?

Comment: This is far too general a question. No one here knows your skill level, what technologies you are familiar with, or which parts of the problem you need help with, what range of routers you want to support, etc., etc.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standard protocol for router command/control.  Most 'domestic' WiFi routers only seem to have web interfaces, and they're all different:(

Comment: actually i read [_this_](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3612951/Wireless-Home-Security-and-Java.htm) link. in this article they explained how to change wep key from java code. now just i want to do same with my router which has same lynksis config file, i have my routers config file but i dont know how to read and write back to it. any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific API or function call you can do to configure those details. You would need to work with router manufactures and their software developers to get something like that integrated with your app

Each router manufacturer has their own router configuration pages with different types of options. There would have to be something at the router hardware level within the router software so your app can communicate with the router.

Comment: +1 - router command/control was a non-standardized, universally hated, miserable exercise when the things had terminal-style config.  Now it's gone web-based and got worse :((

Comment: Check [_this_](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3612951/Wireless-Home-Security-and-Java.htm) link, is that possible in objective-C

Comment: You could probably write a program which works on one model of router such as the Belkin 54G or the Linksys WRT54G but my answer still stands because there is no standard API for a large set of routers.

Comment: Also you need to consider what happens when the manufacturer upgrades the router software, your app could potentially become incompatible with new updates because essentially you are scraping and parsing the Web UI and manipulating it. It's okay as a hack (such as if you want to set your WEP/WPA key according to some algorithm) but not that useful if you want to build a general purpose tool for a large subset of routers